# Django Exception DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, exception, properties, model

I have a model that has Django's model fields AND python properties at the same time. Ex:

**Edit2: Updated with actual models (sorry for the portuguese names)**

```
#On Produto.models.py
from django.db          import models
from django.forms       import ModelForm
from openshift.models   import AbstractModel

from openshift.produto.models import app_name


class Produto(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = app_name


    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=128)    
    und_choices = (
        ('UND', 'Unidade'),
        ('M',     'Metro'),
        ('Kg',     'Quilograma'),
        ('PC',     'Peça'),
    )
    unidade   = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=und_choices, default='UND')

#On Estoque.models.py

from django.db          import models
from django.forms       import ModelForm
from openshift.models   import AbstractModel
from produto.models     import Produto

from openshift.estoque.models import app_name

class Estoque(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = app_name

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    produtoid   = models.ForeignKey(Produto, unique=True)
    quantidade  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
    valorunit   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
    valortotal  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)   


    _field_labels = {
        "id" : r"Código", 
        "produtoid"  : r"Produto", 
        "quantidade" : r"Quantidade",
        "valorunit" : r"Valor Unitário",
        "valortotal" : r"Valor Total"
    }

    _view_order = ['id', 'produtoid', 'quantidade', 'valorunit', 'valortotal']

    @property
    def Vars(self):
        return {'field_labels': self._field_labels, 'view_order': self._view_order}

#on project.views.main_request

obj = get_model('Estoque', 'Estoque')().Vars #Here is where the Exception triggers.
```

If i try to call the property "Vars" before I call the save() method (during the creation of the model's record), django keeps raising a DoesNotExist exception, even though the "Vars" property isnt part of the django model.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

**Edit: As Requested:**

Django Trace:

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/gleal/cbengine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/gleal/cbengine/engine/wsgi/openshift/views.py" in req
>     48.             return browse(request, app, model, var_dict, False)
>
> File
>   "/home/gleal/cbengine/engine/wsgi/openshift/../openshift/subviews/browse.py"
>   in _browse
>     32.         custom_vars['TableColspan']     = len(obj.Vars.get('VIEW_ORDER', {}))
>
> File
>   "/home/gleal/cbengine/engine/wsgi/openshift/../openshift/models.py" in
>   Vars
>     40.             curr_vals[field.name] = getattr(self, field.name)    File
>   "/home/gleal/cbengine/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py"
>   in **get**
>     343.                 raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
>
> Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /estoque/estoque/browse/ Exception
>   Value:

Comment: Why do you even have this property?

Comment: Are you sure that my_vars is not throwing a NameError, not DoesNotExist? Could you show the code that you are using to generate the error and the output?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Its a 'helper' property, that exposes other thing not related directly with the django model, or things that complements the django model attributes.

Comment: Can you post the complete code for your property and the full traceback?

Comment: @SindriGuðmundsson Yes, i'm preaty sure. The code is simply "get_model(my_app,my_model)().my_vars"

Comment: @lealhugui what is var1? Is it a variable defined outside your property definition?

Comment: @SindriGuðmundsson it's suposed to be "var1". Sorry about that. Already edited.

Comment: Please read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because right now we simply lack the proper information to help you.

Comment: @knbk Sorry, but I didnt quite understood. Everythig that is involved on the problem is listed on the exemple. In fact, i can reproduce that same exemple on the django shell, with the exact same lines of code. But if you think that the entire models would help, i will surely edit the exemple :)

Comment: The suspicious thing is that you say the only difference with the actual model is a relation to another model. You wouldn't be referring to that relationship in the `__unicode__` method, by any chance?

Comment: @Daniel The models dont have proper `__unicode__` definition yet. Already updated the exemple with the actual models involved.

Comment: Btw, the traceback is the actual method stack under the heading 'Traceback', not the first part of the error page. If you can post that (click on 'switch to copy-and-paste view' and copy the last part following the word 'traceback'), that could help.

Comment: @knbk  Annnnnd Updated again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that the great villain was the `@property` decorator on the method `Vars`.

It was making django try to get values from the instance of the class, and in some cases, it might trigger some querys on the DB made by the Django's ORM (basically, in cases where i tried to get values from the current instance).

I changed the @property to a @classmethod and everything worked like a charm. Like this:

```
#before
@property
def Vars(self):
    return {'field_labels': self._field_labels, 'view_order': self._view_order}

#after
@classmethod
def Vars(self):
    return {'field_labels': self._field_labels, 'view_order': self._view_order}
```

Thanks to anyone who tried to help!